# assign functions into a window object

Tags: javascript

I'm start working with existing rails application, and I found something i don't understand. Every js function (write as coffe) was declared in followed style.

```
 this.functionA = function(){}
```

and then invoke like:

```
 functionA()
```

There wasn't any namespace, so all of functions was assigned to window object.
I removed `this` because i thought that it is not necessary, but I get error that functionA() does not exist. Why I get this error? And is it a reason to declare function in above style?

Comment: That is weird, because in JS, when declaring something without the `var` keyword, the declaration is attached to the global scope, but I don't know why you receive the undefined error, shouldn't have generated that error, try this instead `var functionA = function(){};`

Comment: You say you're writing coffeescript? CS does declare all used variables locally, so if you invoke `functionA` from somewhere else it won't be available. Explicitly assigning to the global scope might be an antipattern, but it does help here.

Comment: Yest It is writting in coffescript and to be honest all function are declared like @functionA = function(){}, and I removed '@' but I think that this is the same like in my question.